# Getting syntax error in pine script using variable i

Tags: error-handling, pine-script

```
percentage_changes[i] = ((open_price_at_end_date - open_price_after_start_date) / open_price_after_start_date) * 100
```

`=` sign causes error - can somebody provide a solution for this issue? I need to compare paste data for same dates

Answer (score 0):

```
percentage_changes[i] = ((open_price_at_end_date - open_price_after_start_date) / open_price_after_start_date) * 100
```

is not valid `pinescript` syntax.

If you want to set the value of an element in an array, you should use `array.set()`. If you want to access the value of an elenement in an array, you should use `array.get()`.